# Missing argument for parameter "user" call - SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui

I've been getting this error message in the "ProfileFeedView_Previews" and I could not figure out how to solve it. Help would be much appreciated.

Error Message: Missing argument for parameter "user" call

Here are my codes:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProfileFeedView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ProfileViewModel
    let columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0, alignment: nil)]
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.viewModel = ProfileViewModel(user: user)
    }
    var body: some View {

            NavigationView {
                ScrollView{
                    LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 5) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.folders) { folder in
                            FolderLineItem(folder: folder)
                        }
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Folders")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .padding(.top, 50)
        }
    }
}

struct ProfileFeedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileFeedView()


class ProfileViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var folders = [Folder]()
    private let service = FolderService()
    let user: User
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        self.fetchUserFolders()
    }
    
    func fetchUserFolders() {
        guard let uid = user.id else { return }
        
        service.fetchUserFolders(forUID: uid) { folders in
            self.folders = folders
            
            for i in 0 ..< folders.count {
                self.folders[i].user = self.user
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FolderLineItem: View {
    let folder: Folder
    
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
                Image("Image 4")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 15, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) - 15)
                    .clipped()
                    .cornerRadius(8)
                Text(folder.foldername)
                    .font(.callout)
                    .lineLimit(2)
                    .padding(.bottom, 15)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
            
        }
    }
}

struct FolderService {

func fetchUserFolders(forUID uid: String, completion: @escaping([Folder]) -> Void) {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("folders")
            .whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
            .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
                let folders = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Folder.self)})
                completion(folders.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp.dateValue() > $1.timestamp.dateValue()}))
            }
    }
}

struct Folder: Identifiable, Decodable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let foldername: String
    let folderdescription: String
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    let uid: String
    
    var user: User?
}
```

I am lost, and could not figured out what's causing the error. For context, I am a newbie and has only been coding for 2 months.

Comment: This looks incomplete `struct ProfileFeedView_Previews` is that the actual code or you just didnt copy and paste all of it. The formatting in the question may be off as well. Can you clarify?

Comment: I have updated the preview with this. The error from this view went away, but once i link this view to the Tab Bar view, I still get the same error. Also, the data is not returning any filtered data in the forEarch. I am trying to filter it based on the uid of the logged in user. --->>> struct ProfileFeedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {ProfileFeedView(user: User(id: NSUUID().uuidString,
            email:"user@email",
            firstname: "userfirstname",
            lastname: "userlastname"
        ))

Comment: Can you address my above question as the code seems incomplete. Also, there are a lot of places this code could silently fail an you'll never know about it. For example this code `guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }` could fail and you won't be notified. Some troubleshooting would be needed to understand the issue; please add breakpoints and step through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected. Then once you determine where the code is failing, update the question with that info.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProfileFeedView` has an `init` function that receives a `User`:

```
init(user: User) {
  self.viewModel = ProfileViewModel(user: user)
}
```

That means that you can't create an instance of that view without a user. But in your preview, that's what you try to do:

```
struct ProfileFeedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ProfileFeedView()
  }
}
```

(Added in closing braces, I assume that's a copy-and-paste error!)

You will need to have some way of creating a `User` object that your preview can access. How you do that can vary quite a lot, depending on where this information comes from in a "live" context.

But if `User` can be populated easily, one thing you can do is create an `example` static method that creates a user filled with dummy data:

```
extension User {
  static var example: User {
     User(name: "Jane Doe", ...) // etc
  }
}
```

Then, in your preview, you can cite this sample user:

```
struct ProfileFeedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ProfileFeedView(user: User.example)
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the preview with this. The error from this view went away, but once i link this view to the Tab Bar view, I still get the same error. Also, the data is not returning any filtered data in the forEarch. I am trying to filter it based on the uid of the logged in user. --->>> struct ProfileFeedView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {ProfileFeedView(user: User(id: NSUUID().uuidString,
            email:"user@email",
            firstname: "userfirstname",
            lastname: "userlastname"
        ))